# How does the magnetic field strength of a cylinder shaped magnet change as you reach the core(read the description)

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

How does the magnetic flux density of a cylinder shaped magnet mathematically change as you reach the core? does it get stronger or weaker? by how much so, I DON'T mean core going from north to south, but from the outside edge of the diameter of the pole to the center of the diameter of the pole.

Comment: Is this a solid cylinder or a hollow one?

Comment: It is not hollow, it's a solid object, just assume it can be hypothetically entered and examined without disrupting said field.